# Is this endomorphism orthogonal?

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

Let  $F : \mathbb R^3 \to \mathbb R^3$ be defined by  $$F(x_1,x_2,x_3)= \left(-\frac{1}{2}x_1-\frac{\sqrt3}{2}x_2+\frac{1}{2};-\frac{\sqrt3}{2}x_1+\frac{1}{2}x_2+\frac{\sqrt3}{6};-x_3 \right)$$

I know what I have to do in general , look at the matrix and see if its determinant is equal to $\pm 1$ but in this case I also have a translation , so I am not sure on how to work . Really thanks.

Comment: Even for a linear map, having determinant equal to $\pm 1$ is not sufficient to be orthogonal...

Comment: Hi  thanks for answering ,personally I don't know any other condition to see if it is orthogonal other than this

Comment: What does orthonormal mean for a map that is not linear?

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos Hi my profesor only gave me this  defintion :  a matrix is orthogonal if $A*A^t=I$ and always said to represent everything using matrix. That's my problem

Comment: There are no matrices in your question.

Comment: yes but i can reprensent  F as a moltipliation between a matrix and a vector , but i will always have the translation part

Comment: @Dsrksidemath The definition of orthogonality (for a linear map) is, as you said, that $A A^T = I$. This is not equivalent to have determinant $\pm 1$. Now you should look what orthogonal means for an affine map.

Comment: @TheSilverDoe oh ok thanks , Do you know where I can see this concept because I don't have a definition for that , i am very apologize